# Two-sided z-test

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Report states that the mean cost of raising a child from birth to age 2 in a rural area is $\$8,000$ with a standard deviation of $\$1500.$ A random sample of 900 children shows that the mean cost is $\$7925.$ At $\alpha = 5\%,$ decide if there is enough evidence to conclude that the mean cost is not $\$8000.$

I have

- $H_0: µ = 8000$
- $H_a: µ ≠ 8000$

$Z = (7925 - 8000) / 1500 = -0.05$

$P(Z \le -0.05) + P(Z \ge 0.05) = 2P(Z \ge 0.05) 
= 2[0.5-0.0199] = 0.9692.$

Comment: You need to account for the $n = 900$ children. "When the P-value is very small, doubt the null hypothesis. When the P-value is very large, doubt the model or the method."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rejection region is both $$Z_{statistic} \lt -Z_{critical}$$ and $$Z_{statistic} \gt Z_{critical}$$  Find $Z_{critical}$ using a two sided level of significance $\frac{\alpha}{2}$.

$Z_{critical} = 1.96$

In this case you $-0.05 \gt -1.96$ and $\lt 1.96$ and "hence you do not reject the claim" and **conclude that there is not sufficient evidence that the mean cost is not 8000.**

Comment: Saying there is sufficient evidence that the mean cost is 8000 is **not** the same as saying there is insufficient evidence that the mean cost is not 8000.  The data cannot be used to affirm the null, because the p-value is a conditional probability that assumes $H_0$ is true.

Comment: ya'll got me so confused?????????

Comment: $heropup, changed it.